# Setting Spawn Point for characters instead of random spawning

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a random spawning script that I put in my game for characters to spawn. They spawn all together and sometimes out of the map. This is a picture from the game and script:

[image: Character spawning]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CharacterSpawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float spawnRadius = 7, time = 1.5f;

    public GameObject[] enemies;
    public Transform groupTransform;
    //start with and small value and gradually increase or decrease it until you are happy with the result.
    public float spaceBetweenObjects = 1;


    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(SpawnAnEnemy());
    }

    IEnumerator SpawnAnEnemy()
    {
        Vector2 spawnPos = GameObject.Find("Bengal").transform.position;


    Instantiate(enemies[Random.Range(0, enemies.Length)], spawnPos, Quaternion.identity, groupTransform);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
        StartCoroutine(SpawnAnEnemy());

    }
}
```

What should I do to make characters spawn in front of the door of the shop  one by one when I set the time of spawn and radius?
After spawning in front of the door, they should only move towards the desk.

Comment: but your code shows that spawnPos is only one position?

Comment: Yes but they spawn squashed together i dont know i want them to spawn one at a time. Is it because i put them in a group?

Comment: no, because your spawnpos is same

Comment: So what do i do to make them spwn one after another